# Can FormPage be used to upload a file (a CSV to be specific)?

Tags: import, formpage

I want to use **FormPage** to give the user an option to upload a CSV file and once it is uploaded, the data from the file should be plotted. How can this be done?

Thanks!

Comment: It should be straightforward, e.g. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/110525/5478, just replace FormFunction with FormPage

Comment: Thank you so much!