# How do I use the SystemDialogInput feature in WolframCloud?

Tags: wolfram-cloud, systemdialoginput

I will design content using Manipulate on WolframCloud.

I want the SystemDialogInput navigation window to open when I click the button created in Manipulate .

```
obj = Manipulate[Show[ColorConvert[img, "Grayscale"], ImageSize -> 100],
        Row[{Button["File open", img = Import[SystemDialogInput["FileOpen", "*.*"]], 
             Method -> "Queued"]}  ],
        AppearanceElements -> None,Initialization :> (img = Graphics[{Red, Disk[]}] ) ]

CloudPublish[obj, "temp/question.nb"]
```

https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/95fe4d51-6b5d-42e8-970d-c9f20bb181c6

How do I use the SystemDialogInput feature in WolframCloud?

Comment: If you try it it says: `SystemDialogInput::cloudf : SystemDialogInput is not currently supported in the Wolfram Cloud .`

Comment: Yes, I know. Is there a way to operate like SystemDialogInput on Wolfram Cloud?

Comment: Should it have access to visitors file system or your cloud account's?

Comment: I'm trying to upload an image file that exists on his device by an accessor.

Comment: If you don't need a flexibility of Maniupulate maybe a FormPage/FormFunction would fit your needs? see [110525](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/110525/ensuring-that-a-file-uploaded-via-formfunction-is-of-a-particular-type)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 
But I don't want an independent pop-up window like FormPage. 
I want to insert the same function as FormPage inside Manipulate. 
Alternatively, Manipulate and FormPage can be represented on a single webpage or linked together.